# MySQL Deablock in Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql

I have the following table user_sessions:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_sessions` (
  `session_key` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `guid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_key`),
  KEY `FK_user_sessions_user_logins` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_user_sessions_user_logins` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_logins` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then I have SP that is doing some logic. Almost all statements within this SP are `SELECT` except one query where I'm doing update of `user_sessions` with the following query:

```
UPDATE user_sessions
    SET updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, guid = @guid
WHERE session_key = _token;
```

On this query I'm getting this error: `Error Code: 1213. Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

Here is the log from MySQL v 5.7

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 85234691, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 108 lock struct(s), heap size 24784, 7702 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 176542, OS thread handle 46953148479232, query id 66288172 1.1.1.1 db updating
UPDATE user_sessions
                    SET updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, guid = @guid
                WHERE session_key = _token
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2614 page no 3 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `db`.`user_sessions` trx id 85234691 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 21 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 8; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 30; hex 61373366393238612d313137642d313165632d386638322d306135303537; asc a73f928a-117d-11ec-8f82-0a5057; (total 36 bytes);
 1: len 6; hex 0000051493f0; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex bc000001ee0110; asc        ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800000000000000a; asc         ;;
 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 5: len 5; hex 99aa92ed4b; asc     K;;
 6: len 5; hex 99aa92ed4b; asc     K;;
 7: len 30; hex 6b6f6c656b746f2d6170692d383164643233366638393865343932666234; asc db-api-81dd236f898e492fb4; (total 44 bytes);

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 85234689, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
108 lock struct(s), heap size 24784, 7702 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 176541, OS thread handle 46953147946752, query id 66288171 1.1.1.1 db updating
UPDATE user_sessions
                    SET updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, guid = @guid
                WHERE session_key = _token
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 2614 page no 3 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `db`.`user_sessions` trx id 85234689 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 21 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 8; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 30; hex 61373366393238612d313137642d313165632d386638322d306135303537; asc a73f928a-117d-11ec-8f82-0a5057; (total 36 bytes);
 1: len 6; hex 0000051493f0; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex bc000001ee0110; asc        ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800000000000000a; asc         ;;
 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 5: len 5; hex 99aa92ed4b; asc     K;;
 6: len 5; hex 99aa92ed4b; asc     K;;
 7: len 30; hex 6b6f6c656b746f2d6170692d383164643233366638393865343932666234; asc db-api-81dd236f898e492fb4; (total 44 bytes);

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2614 page no 3 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `kolekto`.`user_sessions` trx id 85234689 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 21 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 8; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 30; hex 61373366393238612d313137642d313165632d386638322d306135303537; asc a73f928a-117d-11ec-8f82-0a5057; (total 36 bytes);
 1: len 6; hex 0000051493f0; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex bc000001ee0110; asc        ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800000000000000a; asc         ;;
 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 5: len 5; hex 99aa92ed4b; asc     K;;
 6: len 5; hex 99aa92ed4b; asc     K;;
 7: len 30; hex 6b6f6c656b746f2d6170692d383164643233366638393865343932666234; asc kolekto-api-81dd236f898e492fb4; (total 44 bytes);

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

I tried to use the wrapper function that catches deadlock and try 2 more times to call SP as a prepared statement, and it helps almost in all cases, but since I added user_sessions table - it stoped.
Also, tried to use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` but without success

Comment: are you updating the same tokens at the same time, then rethink your model and concept

Comment: @nbk Can you explain it more? I update time only for single token

Comment: when you run your first update it will row lock the rows ijn question and as it seems you have more than once update the same again and again, this you must avoid, so don't update the same token, look fpor4 another solution

Comment: otherwise, if I have 2+ concurrent requests that call this SP I have to avoid it. Am I right?

Comment: i can't help you, as i can't understand why the lock is so long. my basic assuption you make something that it takes so long loops  for example. see wi9t userdefie vaaibles how long every query takes or enable general log and see what happens at the server

Comment: I would assume that the issue is somewhere else in your code than just this single update, e.g. something else that locks (maybe you have locking selects and/or serializable isolation level). Can you share details about the rest of your stored procedure?

Comment: Hello, I resolved this issue by moving UPDATE statement into a separate SP